# Concatenating Matrices with for loop command in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Consider the reproducible data in which we generate 5 random matrices. Now I want to combine the data in the first row of each matrix

```
set.seed(123)

Result <- foreach(i=1:5) %do%{
  # randomly select number of rows and columns  
  random.rows <- sample(1:5, 1)
  random.columns <- sample(1:5, 1)
  # generate matrix out of this
  matrix(sample(1:100, random.rows*random.columns), random.rows)
}
```

The desired output should take the form:

```
c(Result[[1]][1,], Result[[2]][1,], Result[[3]][1,] # ........
  )
```

I am trying to implement a `for-loop` as in real life, i have more than 5 matrices. Can someone guide me towards my desired output

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  desired_out <- c(Result[[i]][1,])
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a lapply-do.call combination?

Comment: No, namely because I dont know what that is

Comment: That would look like `do.call(c, lapply(Result, function(x) x[1, ]))`.